# Does it make sense to flag a question as duplicate if it already has an answer?

Tags: discussion, flagging, exact-duplicates

I guess the purpose of flagging a post as duplicate is to prevent people from taking the effort to answer a question that has been answered before. So does it make sense to flag a question if someone has already answered it? Are there other reasons why a duplicate question should be flagged as such other than the one I've mentioned?

Comment: The closing of a duplicate is a bit different from the other closure reasons.  It is not as much a matter of preventing or discouraging new Answers as linking the duplicates together so that all good Answers can be more easily found by future searchers.

Comment: Yes, it usually makes *a lot of sense* to flag any question that may be a duplicate of another.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes. It does.

It helps to sort the site, it helps to point people to *more* answers, and it helps to signal that perhaps one should search the site before posting a question.

Comment: And it also helps to signal that perhaps one should search the site before posting an answer.

Comment: I feel that the phrase "perhaps one should search...before posting a question" implies that searching would have been successful (which is not always the case - with many of the duplicated I have flagged I only flagged them because I *know* the original is there and I then spend a while searching for it). I don't know what this phrase should be replaced with though.